# Storing a copy of a document embedded in another document in MongoDB via Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We have a requirement to store a copy of a Mongo document, as an embedded subdocument in another document. It should have a reference to the original document. The copied document needs to be a deep copy, like a snapshot of the original.

The original document's schema (defined with Mongoose) is not fixed - 
it currently uses a type of inheritance to allow different additions to the Schema depending on "type".

---

1. Is there a way to such a flexible embedded schema within a Mongoose model?
2. Is it something that needs to be injected at runtime, when we can know
   the schema?

---

The models / schemas we have currently look like this:

```
///UserList Schema: - this should contain a deep copy of a List
user: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
list: {
    /* Not sure if this is a how we should store the reference 
    type: ObjectId,  
    ref: 'List'
     */
    listId: ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    items: [{
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: 'Item'
    }]
}
```

---

```
///List Schema:

name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
items: [{
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'Item'
}],
createdBy: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

---

The code we currently have uses inheritance to allow different item types. I realise this technique may not be the best way to achieve the flexibility we require and is not the focus of my question.

```
///Item Model + Schema
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
nodeutils = require('util'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
ObjectId = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

function ItemSchema() {
    var self = this;
    Schema.apply(this, arguments);

    self.add({
        question: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    });

    self.methods.toDiscriminator = function(type) {
        var Item = mongoose.model('Item');
        this.__proto__ = new Item.discriminators[type](this);
        return this;
    };
}

nodeutils.inherits(ItemSchema, Schema);
module.exports = ItemSchema;
```

Comment: Nicely formatted question!

Comment: Simply out of curiosity: where does this requirement come from? From my point of view, this is pretty useless data redundancy.

Comment: Normally it would be, but in this case we need to make a copy of some data as it exists at that point in time, as the source data could be changed. Its important that the user has a copy of the data that exists at that moment.

Comment: I made the same for a billing app, allowing to maintain a full hard copy of the data. After that, when user lists it´s data, is all as it was despite the users new configurations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to create an empty {} object for the document in your parent mongoose schema. This way you´ll be able to store any object with a hardcopy of all it´s data.

```
parentobj : {
    name: Sring,
    nestedObj: {}
}
```

I think at this point, what you´ll need is to mark your nested objet as modified before you save it. Here is an example of my mongoose code.

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, eluser) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!eluser) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(eluser, req.body);
    //This makes NESTEDDATA  OBJECT to be saved
    updated.markModified('nestedData');
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, eluser);
    });
  });
};
```

In addition, if you need an array of different documents in nestedDocument, the right way is this one:

```
parentobj : {
    name: Sring,
    nestedObjs: [Schema.Types.Mixed]
}
```

Please check [Mongoose Schema Types](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) carefully

**EDIT**

As you said, I´ll add you final solution as including ItemSchema in the nestedObj array definition to clarifythe type of the object to a determined one..

```
var ItemSchema = new Schema({
    item1: String,
    item2: String
});

var parentobj = new Schema({
    name: Sring,
    nestedObj: [ItemSchema]
});
```

**EDIT 2:**
Remember adding new Items to the nestedArray, must be done with nestedArray.push(item)

regards!!

Comment: I have added ```items: [ItemSchema]``` in my List schema which seems to do what I need, as all those Items will inherit from ItemSchema. 
If you wish to update your answer to include this I will gladly accept your answer.

Comment: bu you said it was different schemaTypes in the same place, that´s Mixed, isn´t it???

Adding also the itens:[ItemSchema] to make the solution complete! .. Thanks!!